# Flutter Dropdown and Text Field is not showing in Release Mode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-release

My flutter app is not showing a Dropdown field and a text field in release mode, but in debug everything seems fine, I have no idea why this is happening.

I'm using a dropdown_search package to show the dropdown field, and a CustomTextField package to show the text field.

here is my full code. (DropdownSearch) and (CustomTextField)

```
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: DropdownSearch<String>(
            popupProps: const PopupProps.menu(
              showSelectedItems: true,
            ),
            items: [
              'Option 1',
              'Option 2',
              'Option 3'
            ],
            dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
              dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Choose',
                hintText: 'Choose',
              ),
            ),
            onChanged: print,
            selectedItem: 'Option 1',
          )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: CustomTextField(
              controller: num1controller,
              showCancelIcon: true,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter Number',
                hintText: 'Enter Number',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Calculate'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                double sum = double.tryParse(num1controller.text) ?? 1;
                final sum1 = sum / calculation;
                result = sum1.toStringAsFixed(3);
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Result',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.black12,
                child: Text(
                  '$result',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ])
```

I have no idea why its happening

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `Expanded` as child of a listview. `Expanded` can only be used inside flex widgets like `Column` and `Row`. Your console should also be showing errors because of that, even in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you can remove the `expanded` from the parent of `DropdownSearch` and `Customtextfield` or wrap both `expanded` in the `row` widget.